# Chrome profile to disable "Know your location" pop up

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running my tests in Google Chrome using `chromedriver.exe` binary. At one particular page this pop up comes which doesn't intervene/effect with the test but client doesn't want to see it. Possible reason could be, at the failure of test case it will capture the screenshot along with this pop up.

How can I create a chrome `profile` or `capabilities` which would disable this pop up?

[image]

Something like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
```

**Edit:**

This code stopped the "Know your location" pop up to come but generated another pop up. So its only partially working.
    `options.addArguments("--enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use `--disable-geolocation`, Chrome Options as given below:

```
options.addArguments("--disable-geolocation");
```

Also list of chrome command-line switches can be found in the below link:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: `chrome.switches= --incognito, --disable-geolocation` not working. It opens in incognito but couldn't stop location pop up

Answer (score 1):

Declaring in the following way worked for me.

```
// Declare variables
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Map<String, Object> contentSettings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// Specify the ChromeOption we need to set
 contentSettings.put(“geolocation”, 1);
 profile.put(“managed_default_content_settings”, contentSettings);
 prefs.put(“profile”, profile);
 options.setExperimentalOption(“prefs”, prefs);
// Declare the capability for ChromeOptions
 caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code solved my problem with geolocation

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2);
```

Comment: why `_options` and not `options`?

Answer (score 1):

The `--disable-geolocation` flag didn't do anything for me.
I am also running with incognito on, so that might be affecting some things.

I can confirm that the following python selenium code will disable the location popup

```py
        prefs = {
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

In the interest of digging deeper.
If you need to change any setting. It can be done by comparing the "${PROFILE}Preferences" file that is saved

I'd recommend always starting with a clean profile as follows, then setting whatever preferences you want in code. to get a reproducible result.

```py
        data_dir = "tmp/remote-profile"
        if os.path.exists(data_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(data_dir)
        options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=tmp/remote-profile")
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
```

In the case above the Preferences file will be in `tmp/remote-profile/Default/Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

Add this below command line argument, which will restrict geolocation feature.

```
String url = "http://ctrlq.org/maps/where/";

//Chromedriver Version : 2.19.346078
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "CHROMEDRIVERPATH");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(url);
```

And other way is after lauching the chrome browser, Through the selenium code implement below steps which will disable the geo location popup.

- Go to : chrome://settings/content
- Under the location select 'Do not allow any site to track your physical location' option.

[image: Do not allow any site to track your physical location]

- Click On **Done**

Comment: I have tried both, by setting the `chromeoptions` and disabling from `chrome://settings/content`, but none worked.

Comment: I have verified for chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m, It is working fine. Which version you are using ?

Comment: same! If I running test case 10 times, I do not want to go to settings/content and block it. I have set it once in my local chrome browser and once in chromeoptions. And its not working.

Comment: I just tried with below argument , it is working fine.
"options.addArguments("--enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");"
Which  chromedriver version you are using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100441/discussion-between-shoaib-mal-and-paul).