# how to close facebook localisation alert with selenium?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, alert

I'm coding a Facebook bot. But I face a problem. Every Time I log in to facebook account, a Localisation alert appear and break everything. 
This a picture of the alert:

[image]
I tried "switch_to_alert method" but it does not works.

This is my code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert= driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

I use python with selenium. Hope you can help me.
Thanks !

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721359/chrome-profile-to-disable-know-your-location-pop-up.

Comment: html code? the generic alert methods may not suffice