# How to ignore geo location popup using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After allowing  for "all the site to get your physical location" using chrome setting, still popup getting populated. How to handle geo location popup using java selenium? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions already?

[question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721359/chrome-profile-to-disable-know-your-location-pop-up/34723230#34723230)

[question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390611/how-can-i-allow-location-access-using-selenium/28390721#28390721)

Comment: Both the way i have tried,but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

To disable this message you need to add chrome options:

```
options.addArguments("--enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");
options.addArguments("--disable-geolocation");
```

Full example:

```
public WebDriver createDriver(){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("disable-notifications");
    options.addArguments("--enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");
    options.addArguments("--disable-geolocation");
    return new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```