# Watir Click JS Button

Tags: javascript, watir

I can't seem to get past a `button` in a landing page.  Here is the `JS` element with parent nodes:

```
<div class="modal-body-content callfor-popup">
  <h3>Welcome | Bienvenue</h3>

  <p class="body_M_normal" aria-level="4" role="heading">Please select a language | Veuillez sélectionner une langue</p>

  <div class="small_btn lcbo_cookie">
    <a class="body_M_normal" href="https://www.lcbo.com/en/stores/store/redirect/___store/en/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGNiby5jb20vZW4v/">English</a>
  </div>

  <div class="small_btn lcbo_cookie">
    <a class="body_M_normal" href="https://www.lcbo.com/en/stores/store/redirect/___store/fr/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGNiby5jb20vZnIv/">Français</a>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <p class="caption_xxs_noletterspace">
    You must be 19 years of age to purchase alcohol. Please note that we only deliver in Ontario / Vous devez avoir au moins 19 ans pour acheter de l'alcool. Veuillez noter que nous ne livrons pas à l'extérieur de l’Ontario.
  </p>
</div>
```

This is what I am currently trying:

```
    puts '1' if a.element(visible_text: 'English').exist?
    puts '2' if a.link(visible_text: 'English').exist?
    puts '3' if a.button(text: 'English').exist?
    puts '4' if a.link(visible_text: 'English').exist?
    puts '5' if a.element(visible_text: 'English').exist?

    a.button(text: 'English').click
    a.element(visible_text: 'English').click
    a.link(visible_text: 'English').click
    
    puts "clicks finished"
```

1, 2, 4 and 5 show up, indicating `Watir` knows they are there and exist.  I can't seem to click that `element` though.  It's not a formal `HTML` `button`, so that's why I'm trying several `elements`.

Is there a better way of dealing with such `JS` elements?  I'm not sure how to focus on the **English** option.

Comment: Confused what you are doing. The element is not actually a button, but a link element dressed up to look like a button. 1 & 5, 2 & 4 look like the same thing? What happens when you do `a.link(visible_text: 'English').click`? Do you get an error or just nothing happening? I'm guessing it isn't a race condition where waiting a second causes it to work? Might also try `a.link(visible_text: 'English').parent.click` in case the fancy JS stuff is attached to the parent div.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way of choosing this `element`, so the dialog box goes away.  There might be some repeats on those troubleshooting lines.  None of these make the dialog box disappear.  I have a `sleep` for 3 to 6 seconds before and after.  The page is here: [LCBO](https://www.lcbo.com).  Oh, and `.parent` didn't work.

Comment: Using `browser.link(text: 'English').click` worked for me. If your examples, what is `a`?

Comment: a is my browser.  Will have another look.  Did that dialog box disappear for you?

Comment: The box asking for your location? Might need to add an option to your Capabilities so it never shows up - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721359/chrome-profile-to-disable-know-your-location-pop-up

Comment: Will check that out.  Just thought it easy to deal with the button.  JS derived **buttons** are an odd trick without an `id`.

Comment: @JustinKo That was the answer.  Want to post it as a full response?